# Best practices: the best position for javascript including render. Rails3.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

My Environment

```
Rails 3.2.1
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
```

I use jQuery like this.

```
$('.foo').append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'bar') %>");
```

First, I wrote in the eruby file with content_for.

```
 <% content_for :script do %> 
   <%= javascript_tag do -%>
     $('.foo').append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'bar') %>");
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

However the part of javascript became large, so I want to move javascript to the other file.
then I am trouble where the file should be.

now I make directory "$RAILS_ROOT/app/views/js/" and create the file into it.

```
 <% content_for :script do %> 
   <%= render 'js/foo' %>
 <% end %>
```

so I want to know the best place for javascript including render.

Many thanks in advance.